# Matlab: How to trace/debug a model running on MCR

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I've a third party model that is packaged up in  a jar file, and running on an MCR on Linux.

There is no real logging though with this model, so I've no real idea what it is doing when it is running.

Is there any way to trace/debug the model runtime easily without having to pepper it with outputs to the console?

Something similar to a Java thread dump would be very useful!

Comment: The MCR is designed to have your code run on machines without a MATLAB license, or to share your programs with others in such a way that they can't fiddle with your code. I'd be surprised if they had built in debugging facilities. But jar files are Java, do you mean CTF?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I believe the jar file contains a Java class and then Matlab code embedded in a ctf file. It's the Matlab piece I need to understand what it's doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, one of the purposes of packaging up a MATLAB application into a standalone component like this is to prevent you from seeing the internals.

You'd need to speak with the authors of the component, and ask them either to see the source code, or for them to instrument it with logging and recreate the component.